# SQL Server - Renumber in Order

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that I need to reorder a column, but I need to keep the original order by date.

```
TABLE_1
id                                   num_seq  DateTimeStamp
fb4e1683-7035-4895-b2c8-d084d9b42ce3 111      08-02-2005
e40e4c3e-65e4-47b7-b13a-79e8bce2d02d 114      10-07-2017
49e261a8-a855-4844-a0ac-37b313da2222 113      01-30-2010
6c4bffb7-a056-4a20-ae1c-5a31bdf683f2 112      04-15-2006
```

I want to reorder num_seq starting with 1001 through 1004 and keep the numbering in order. So 111 = 1001 and 112 = 1002 and so forth.
This is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @num INT 
SET @num = 0 
UPDATE Table_1 
SET @num = num_seq = @id + 1 
GO
```

I know that `UPDATE` doesn't let me use the keyword `ORDER BY`. Is there a way to do this in SQL 2008 R2?

Answer (score 1):

Stage the new `num_seq` in a CTE, then leverage that in your update statement:

```
declare @Table_1 table (id uniqueidentifier, num_seq int, DateTimeStamp datetime);
insert into @Table_1
values
    ('fb4e1683-7035-4895-b2c8-d084d9b42ce3', 111,  '08-02-2005'),
    ('e40e4c3e-65e4-47b7-b13a-79e8bce2d02d', 114,  '10-07-2017'),
    ('49e261a8-a855-4844-a0ac-37b313da2222', 113,  '01-30-2010'),
    ('6c4bffb7-a056-4a20-ae1c-5a31bdf683f2', 112,  '04-15-2006');

;with stage as 
(
    select  *, 
            num_seq_new = 1000 + row_number()over(order by DateTimeStamp asc)
    from    @Table_1
)
update stage
set    num_seq = num_seq_new;


select * from @Table_1
```

Returns:

```
id                                      num_seq DateTimeStamp
FB4E1683-7035-4895-B2C8-D084D9B42CE3    1001    2005-08-02 00:00:00.000
E40E4C3E-65E4-47B7-B13A-79E8BCE2D02D    1004    2017-10-07 00:00:00.000
49E261A8-A855-4844-A0AC-37B313DA2222    1003    2010-01-30 00:00:00.000
6C4BFFB7-A056-4A20-AE1C-5A31BDF683F2    1002    2006-04-15 00:00:00.000
```